# Regex :: Complex Substitutions

Tags: regex, string-substitution

I am trying to "prettify" a certain type of number object in my solution. This particular type has the following possible representations, along with their pretty representations:

```
xxxxxyyyyyyy  => xxxxx-yyyyyyy
xxxxxyyyyyyyz => xxxxx-yyyyyyy-z
```

Basically, the type consists of 5 digits denoting `FieldA`, 7 digits denoting `FieldB` and an optional digit denoting a `CheckDigit`. Using the following regex/replace patterns:

```
Regex:       ^(?<FIELDA>\d{5})(?<FIELDB>\d{7})(?<CHECKDIGIT>\d?)$
Replacement: ${FIELDA}-${FIELDB}-${CHECKDIGIT}
```

... results in:

```
xxxxxyyyyyyy  => xxxxx-yyyyyyy-  (wrong)
xxxxxyyyyyyyz => xxxxx-yyyyyyy-z (correct)
```

Is it possible correcting the first representation using just a regex/replace pair? **I can make this work by using two different regexes** but i would like a more elegant solution than that. One that uses a single regex/replacement pair.

PS. I'm using Java 1.7.

Comment: The fastest way -> Should be `^(?<FIELDA>\d{5})(?<FIELDB>\d{7})(?<CHECKDIGIT>\d)?$` then in a callback check if group 3 matched. Otherwise, try to replace individually if Java supports the `\G` construct.

Comment: im not sure i follow completely.. care to elaborate a bit more mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in a single RegEx in the tool. You can use two RegEx as follow.

First, replace the numbers with `-` in between.

> Search: [`^(\d{5})(\d{7})(\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/rC8rF4/1)
>
> Replace: `$1-$2-$3`

[image: First Replacement]

Then, remove the trailing dash.

> Search: [`^(\d{5})-(\d{7})-$`](https://regex101.com/r/rC8rF4/2)
>
> Replace: `$1-$2`

[image: Second Replacement]

[image: End Result]

Comment: yea thats a possible solution as well.. however, im interested in knowing whether there is a solution that involves only a SINGLE pair of regex/replacement strings.. =/